# Checking for duplicate entries in select box

Tags: javascript

The following function, will dynamically add a new option value into a selectbox. Great feature, but it does not account and check for duplicate entries before adding new options into the select box. How can the code be modified such that it will alert the user that a duplicate entry has been found and to abort adding the same option value:

```
function addref() {

var value = document.getElementById('refdocs').value

    if (value != "") {

        var select = document.getElementById('refdocs_list');

        var option = document.createElement('option');

        option.text = value

        select.add(option,select.option)

        select.selectedIndex = select.options.length - 1;
    }//end of if

}//end of function
```

Comment: iterate over the existing options and check if they equal the new option. if not then add it

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry very amateur javascripter here.

Comment: @JohnSmith the following link shows how to iterate over a select using javascript, Credit to nathan hayfield for finding: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?28688-How-do-you-iterate-through-ALL-the-drop-down-menu-(select)-objects-on-the-form-in-css

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/rcwgk/2/

this will work this adds to both values and options you likely want to do something differently.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var values = new Array();
            var options = new Array();

            if(!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
                Array.prototype.indexOf = function(needle) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                        if(this[i] === needle) {
                            return i;
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                };
            }

            function getOptions() {
                var selectobject=document.getElementById("refdocs_list");
                for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
                    values.push(selectobject.options[i].value);
                    options.push(selectobject.options[i].text);
                }
            }

            function addref() {

                var value = document.getElementById('refdocs').value

                if (value != "" && values.indexOf(value) == -1 && options.indexOf(value) == -1 ) {
                    values.push(value);
                    options.push(value);
                    var select = document.getElementById('refdocs_list');

                    var option = document.createElement('option');

                    option.text = value

                    select.add(option,select.option)

                    select.selectedIndex = select.options.length - 1;
                }//end of if

            }//end of function
        </script>
    </head>
            <body onload="getOptions()">
<select id="refdocs_list">
     <option value="1">test</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="refdocs"/>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="javascript:addref()" />
            </body>
        </html>
```